# request to reopen question about beggars as ptij?

Tags: discussion, policy, specific-question, purim-torah-policy

BH

Hi

I have this post [PTIJ: are beggars obligated to follow hasagas gvul?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/128470/ptij-are-beggars-obligated-to-follow-hasagas-gvul?noredirect=1#comment424584_128470) which was closed because some people didnt get the joke, but i would like to reopen it

the joke is that beggars think theyre going to business when begging, so maybe they should have to follow hasag gvul. but the reality is is that they are merely relying on the generosity of others, and dont "deserve" any of the money theyre getting

Answer (score 4):

The question, as written, would seem to be a perfectly reasonable question about whether the laws of encroachment apply to charity collectors. Adding the [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) tag and disclaimer doesn't take away that fact. I would thus have voted to close the question if it hadn't been already closed, and I would vote to leave it closed if it gets nominated for reopening.

However, if you edit the question to remove the [purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) tag and disclaimer, I would vote to reopen it as a regular question. Alternatively, if you edit the question such that it wouldn't work as a reasonable regular question, I would vote to reopen it as PTIJ.

Comment: can u explain how its reasonable to assume why begging is a business? not talking about charity collectors, talking about begging. but even if I was, same idea

Comment: @Yaakov5777 That’s what the question is.

Comment: no, the question is that, assuming its a business, are they obligated in hasagas givul. but that assumption is so ridiculous its purim torah. can u explain why one would think begging is a business in the first place?

Comment: @Yaakov5777 because there are beggars who actually make begging their actual job. They spent hours a day and don't do anything else.